# Trying to use diff output to compare to a separate file

Tags: diff

I have two files:

```
smw:/working/iso_testing # cat a
QConvergeConsoleCLI-1.1.03-49.x86_64.rpm
aaa_base-13.2+git20140911.61c1681-1.3.i586.rpm
acpica-20140724-2.1.2.i586.rpm
test.rpm
```

AND

```
smw:/working/iso_testing # cat b
QConvergeConsoleCLI-1.1.03-49.x86_64.rpm
aaa_base-13.2+git20140911.61c1681-1.3.i586.rpm
acpica-20140724-2.1.2.i586.rpm
```

--If I diff them I see this:

```
smw:/working/iso_testing # diff a b
4d3
< test.rpm
```

I want to take THAT output (test.rpm) and grep it out of a third file. A.K.A. file c:

```
smw:/working/iso_testing # cat c
QConvergeConsoleCLI QConvergeConsoleCLI-1.1.03-49.x86_64.rpm
aaa_base aaa_base-13.2+git20140911.61c1681-1.3.i586.rpm
acpica acpica-20140724-2.1.2.i586.rpm
test test.rpm
```

My desired output would look something like

```
test test.rpm
```

Perhaps I have to many files to begin with but I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance

File A is the list or rpm's from one repo, file B is a list of rpm's from a .csv file, and file C is a copy of file B but with package names, not just the rpm.***

Answer (score 0):

Here is the TLDR solution:

```bsh
for line in "$(diff a b | sed -n 's/^< //p')"; do grep "${line}" c; done
```

A more detailed explanation follows.

---

Probably the first thing you'll want to do is clean up the output of the `diff` command and extract the strings you want to search for.

Based on your example it looks like you want the lines that only occur in the first file (e.g. file "a").

The following command returns the lines from the first file and removes the "< " prefix:

```bsh
diff <(diff a b | sed -n 's/^< //p')
```

Now you can loop over this cleaned-up diff and grep for each line, e.g.:

```bsh
for line in "$(diff a b | sed -n 's/^< //p')"; do grep "${line}" c; done
```

This approach has the advantage of being pretty flexible, since you can replace the `grep` statement with an arbitrary command.

On the other hand, if you know that just want to search for those fixed strings then you can also use the `-f` flag for `grep` instead of using a for-loop:

```bsh
grep -f <(diff a b | sed -n 's/^< //p') c
```

Another alternative is to invoke `diff` a second time:

```bsh
diff <(diff a b | sed -n 's/^< //p') c
```

You can then process this output in a similar manner:

```bsh
diff <(diff a b | sed -n 's/^< //p') c | sed -n 's/^< //p'
```

Comment: @roaima Thanks - good call. I always grep first and ask questions later.